# ArcGIS Random Point generator producing same points every iteration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, random, sampling, point

I am generating random points to sample within a stratum. 
Data Management Tools > Feature Class > Generate Random Points
This works just fine, except that I noticed the points I generated for sampling this year were exactly the same as last year. Every time I generate a new set of points, they are the same points each time.

Is there a setting that will fix this?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

Comment: You likely need to set a seed value for the random number generator somewhere in the settings. It does not appear to be an argument in the actual tool, which is an absurd over site on ESRI's part.

Answer (score 5):

The tool will always return the same results unless you set the Random Generator environment value. Click the **Environments...** button at the bottom of the tool and select the **Random Numbers** section. See the [help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/random-number-generator.htm) for the Random Number Generator for details.